# AMD ATI Cards in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Unable to access fglrx on a Headless Server

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, fglrx, gpu-driver

I have been dealing with this issue for days. I have tried following guides, stuff on my own, clean installs, different applications and yet the same old thing, unable to see the GPU's in the system for Crunching BOINC applications or BitCoin Farming etc.

It always boils down to FGLRX:

So I the latest attempt was by following a guide to setup a BitCoin mining rig (first time, just experimenting because the guide was suggested to fix the No Detectable GPU's for BOINC).

I am using Ubuntu:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

When I run `sudo aticonfig --lsa` I get:

```
* 0. 01:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
  1. 02:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
```

So I know the cards are there. I ran `sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-core fglrx-dev fglrx-amdcccle` to get the drivers installed.

Then I ran `sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial -f` to configure the xorg.conf file.

I made a few other config changes per the guide and those were:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
sudo update-grub
sudo apt-get install xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-commom
```

Then I got to the part that is vexing me constantly. When I try to test the cards for the mining program (or run BOINC) I get:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 
kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='fglrx'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fglrx': Function not implemented
Error! Fail to load fglrx kernel module! Maybe you can switch to root user to load kernel module directly
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='fglrx'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fglrx': Function not implemented
Error! Fail to load fglrx kernel module! Maybe you can switch to root user to load kernel module directly
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='fglrx'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fglrx': Function not implemented
Error! Fail to load fglrx kernel module! Maybe you can switch to root user to load kernel module directly

$uname -a
Linux cruncher 4.4.0-57-generic #78~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Dec 10 00:14:47 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo clinfo
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='fglrx'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fglrx': Function not implemented
Error! Fail to load fglrx kernel module! Maybe you can switch to root user to load kernel module directly
*** Error in `clinfo': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f63873e511d ***
```

I am still earning ubuntu so its a learning curve, but I have reached a place where my Google skills are not helping me so I thought I would ask!

I don't have a clue how to get past this. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think FGLRX was deprecated after 14.04.1. You'll either need to roll-back or try the newer amdgpu driver (open source) or amdgpu pro from AMD website (proprietary driver) if your card is listed as supported on the AMD website.

Comment: I think you are right, but your answer could be improved, for example with a link, or some more details.

Comment: Well I seem to have borked the install as I can't get any cards detected now. Can we download install versions that have support for these cards? Like if I want to download Ubuntu 14.04.1 and not 14.04.5. I am going to start looking more but I saw only the 14.05 on the ubuntu 
downloads site so far.

This driver split on these cards is really annoying me. i have several of the R9 270's R9 265's and a few other cards and it seems each uses a different driver.

Comment: You can try either google for something like "ubuntu 14.04.1 download" or try [http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.1/](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.1/) although when I went to 14.04.1 on the top of the page it says 14.04.2